# Springboot - validate "native" properties at startup

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Context: after a recent springboot/spring migration, I've been scratching my head on why my HAL URLs were now returned as HTTP and not HTTPS anymore.

After investigation, this was related to some deprecated (and removed) property replaced by another one (ok, Intellij was doing a proper job and highlighted this)

```
server.use-forward-headers=true
#replaced by
server.forward-headers-strategy=native
```

Whereas I know you can validate your own properties set via your `@ConfigurationProperties`, its parameters or even your own JSR annotations, is there a way to validate "native" properties (server.*, spring.*, ...) at application startup and/or build?

- UC1: I want to be sure I'm not using any unknown property (e.g. the property has been totally removed or is misspelt)
- UC2: I want to be sure I'm not using any deprecated property

Approaches tried:

- Searching for an existing property that would do the job
- Overriding ServerProperties (sounds like a bad idea)
- Using an existing FailureAnalyzer or defining a custom one

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rely on your IDE but it can only show you the configuration files that you are managing. Those properties are potentially set as environment variables in an specific environment or using a remote config server you don't have access to.

That's one of the reasons we're providing `spring-boot-properties-migrator`. It is referenced in the [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#configuration-properties).

Here is a sample [demo app](https://github.com/snicoll-scratches/demo-properties-migrator) that yield the following:

```
2020-07-18 19:19:54.168  INFO 69898 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication on taurus.lan with PID 69898 (/Users/snicoll/Downloads/demo-properties-migrator/target/classes started by snicoll in /Users/snicoll/Downloads/demo-properties-migrator)
2020-07-18 19:19:54.170  INFO 69898 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-07-18 19:19:54.545  INFO 69898 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 0.571 seconds (JVM running for 0.924)
2020-07-18 19:19:54.551 ERROR 69898 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.p.m.PropertiesMigrationListener  : 
The use of configuration keys that are no longer supported was found in the environment:

Property source 'systemProperties':
    Key: server.connection-timeout
        Reason: Each server behaves differently.

Property source 'applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.properties]':
    Key: server.use-forward-headers
        Line: 1
        Reason: Replaced to support additional strategies.


Please refer to the release notes or reference guide for potential alternatives.
```

This will work for known properties (your use case) but it won't work for properties that are set and we don't know about (i.e. that don't have metadata). An obvious candidate in that set is typos of course but that's no longer an upgrade problem. Relying on your IDE to make sure that the property you introduce is legit sounds reasonable to me.

We'd like also to offer some validation for users that are adding properties without assistance, see [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10030) for more details.